# Objective C: How to play a record file

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, avfoundation

good day sir/maam! i am new at objective c and application development.. i just want to ask how im going to play a recorded file that is triggered by high level of threshold? and stop the recording in a period of silence... from the code of [detecting blowing a mic](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) i know that i need to open always the recording function.. then i want to play only the moment i triggered the high threshold until the it detects a period of silence... thanks in advance! more power to you guys..